# Why did this simple code break when I installed jquery 3?

Tags: jquery, migration

I have some very very simple code that does two things.  The first thing it does is, when a checkbox is clicked, it toggles the visibility of a div containing more options.  The second thing it does is uncheck all of the second set of options (subcategories) if the main checkbox is unchecked (categories)

It works absolutely perfectly and does everything I want under jquery 1.12 but when I went in (it's an old site) and switched to jquery 3.3.1 it stopped working.  Nothing shows on the console as far as an error.

I'm not the most brilliant jquery user, so perhaps one of you could point out what is wrong?  I can likely just revert to older jquery as this is in a password protected admin area, but I would rather understand why it isn't working under jquery 3.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('input.categorycheck[type="checkbox"]').click(function(){
    var inputValue = $(this).attr("value");
    $("." + inputValue).toggle();
    $(".subcat" + inputValue).attr("checked", false);

});



});
```

Comment: Can you please post your html structure as well.

Comment: Looks like your actual jQuery code works fine. https://jsfiddle.net/eL7qjy3o/